# Printing a 11x17 booklet

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, pdf

So I am trying to take an inDesign file that takes one page of a document and splits it onto two pages of a 11x17 booklet. For example a landscape orientation image that has a bleed from one page to the other. Also, I have pages of the document that has two sides a split in the middle and I want the left side to be on one page and the right to be on the next page. It usually prints it as a sideways portrait (like a landscape on one page) not a land scape of the two pages. tl:dr Everything I have found for this has putting the same image onto multiple pages or putting multiple pages onto one page but nothing that converts one image half on one page and half on the other. Tried printing from PDF and indesign

Comment: Is there a reason you can't relay it properly as 8.5x11?

Comment: Sorry, What's the question?

Comment: Before anyone can give you a useful answer, you'll have to make the question clear. Is the page size of the finished booklet 8.5x11 (11x17 folded once) or actually 11x17? Is the "it" that prints "as a sideways portrait" the page, or the image? What size are your InDesign pages? A screen shot would be helpful, too.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what you're asking, because your question doesn't make much sense to me.

I believe that you are asking how to split one image across two pages?

If so, ensure that when you make your new document you select "Facing Pages"

[image: facing pages]

Then, when you insert your image, simply make it cover the two facing pages.  Below is a screen shot from something I just finished working on.  You can see that my front and back cover is just one image that I made in Photoshop and then dragged across both pages.

[image: Cover]